# How to pass Robot Framework variable to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, robotframework

I need to pass my Robot variable to JavaScript:

```
${path}=    Set Variable    /apis
${method}=  Set Variable    get
${result}=  Execute Javascript  path_to_file/file.js
Log ${result}
```

I'd like to pass `${path}` and `${method}` to my file.js. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `execute javascript` to create javascript variables.

For example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Example
    ${path}=    Set Variable    /apis
    ${method}=  Set Variable    get

    Execute javascript  path='foobar';
    Execute javascript  method='${method}'

    ${result}=  Execute Javascript  path_to_file/file.js
    Log ${result}
```